# Cesium DataSourceCollection layer ordering

Tags: javascript, z-index, gis, geojson, cesiumjs

I have multiple `GeoJsonDataSource` objects that I want to put on a Cesium globe. The problem is that if they overlap, I get some z-fighting issues and I can't adjust their order.

Is there a way of specifying the order of `DataSource` objects in a `DataSourceCollection`?

For example, I'd like to have the green polygon on top of the red polygon using the following code:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');

var red = Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource.load('map1.geojson', {
  fill: new Cesium.Color(1, 0, 0, 1.0)
});

var green = Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource.load('map2.geojson', {
  fill: new Cesium.Color(0, 1, 0, 1.0)
});

viewer.dataSources.add(red);
viewer.dataSources.add(green);
```

However, the result looks like this:

[image: Cesium screenshot showing z-fighting]

I've noticed that if I adjust the alpha argument to less than `1.0`, I can fix the z-fighting, but the order still does not get addressed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Update 12/2019:

Cesium has added a `zIndex` property to [`PolygonGraphics`](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/PolygonGraphics.html) in the time since this was originally asked.  It's only valid for "ground primitives", for example polygons that lie directly on terrain and do not have `height` or `extrudedHeight` properties assigned to them.  For those, use my original answer below.  But for ground primitives, you can now just assign a `zIndex` like this:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');

var redPolygon = viewer.entities.add({
    name : 'Red polygon',
    polygon : {
        hierarchy : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray([-115.0, 37.0,
                                                        -115.0, 32.0,
                                                        -102.0, 31.0,
                                                        -102.0, 38.0]),
        material : new Cesium.Color(1, 0, 0),
        zindex : 1
    }
});

var greenPolygon = viewer.entities.add({
    name : 'Green polygon',
    polygon : {
        hierarchy : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray([-118.0, 42.0,
                                                        -100.0, 42.0,
                                                        -104.0, 32.0]),
        material : new Cesium.Color(0, 1, 0),
        zIndex : 2
    }
});

viewer.zoomTo(viewer.entities);
```

#### Original answer:

At the bottom of your question, you mentioned the quick-fix for z-fighting is to simply to turn off the Z buffer for these polygons, by setting some transparency.  Transparency happens in an 8-bit Alpha channel, so my favorite value to use is `254.0 / 255.0`, or `0.996`.

But there's another option you'll probably want to turn off, and that's `orderIndependentTranslucency`.  This is a property of `Scene` that can be initialized from an options parameter in Viewer's constructor.  When left on, the default for systems that support it, one can always "see" translucent objects behind other translucent objects, regardless of the opacity, and of course the render order doesn't affect the result.  But in this case, you *want* the render order to affect the result, if you want one polygon to obscure the other one.

Here's an example.  Click "Run Code Snippet" at the bottom, or paste just the JavaScript section into [Sandcastle](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Hello%20World.html&label=All).

```js
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    navigationInstructionsInitiallyVisible: false, animation: false, timeline: false,

    // The next line is the important option for this demo.
    // Test how this looks with both "true" and "false" here.
    orderIndependentTranslucency: false
});

var redPolygon = viewer.entities.add({
    name : 'Red polygon',
    polygon : {
        hierarchy : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray([-115.0, 37.0,
                                                        -115.0, 32.0,
                                                        -102.0, 31.0,
                                                        -102.0, 38.0]),
        // The alpha of 0.996 turns off the Z buffer.
        material : new Cesium.Color(1, 0, 0, 0.996)
    }
});

var greenPolygon = viewer.entities.add({
    name : 'Green polygon',
    polygon : {
        hierarchy : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray([-118.0, 42.0,
                                                        -100.0, 42.0,
                                                        -104.0, 32.0]),
        // The alpha of 0.996 turns off the Z buffer.
        material : new Cesium.Color(0, 1, 0, 0.996)
    }
});

viewer.zoomTo(viewer.entities);
```

```css
html, body, #cesiumContainer {
  width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.19/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" 
      rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.19/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js">
</script>
<div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer is simple, You can add `z-index` in your code.

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');

var red = Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource.load('map1.geojson', {
  fill: new Cesium.Color(1, 0, 0, 1.0),
  zIndex: 1
});

var green = Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource.load('map2.geojson', {
  fill: new Cesium.Color(0, 1, 0, 1.0),
  zIndex: 2
});

viewer.dataSources.add(red);
viewer.dataSources.add(green);
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be useful for a bit different case:
[image]
polygons have heights and some of them might be transparent or not , also polygon layers lie on top of each other.
For resolving  z-fighting in this case the good approach is removing bottom part of polygons with option flag  {closeBottom: false}.
I have adapted code for this case from   above comment:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
navigationInstructionsInitiallyVisible: false, animation: false, timeline: false,

// The next line is the important option for this demo.
// Test how this looks with both "true" and "false" here.
orderIndependentTranslucency: false
});

var redPolygon = viewer.entities.add({
name : 'Red polygon',
polygon : {
    hierarchy : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray([-115.0, 37.0,
                                                    -115.0, 32.0,
                                                    -102.0, 31.0,
                                                    -102.0, 38.0]),
    // The alpha of 0.996 turns off the Z buffer.
    material : new Cesium.Color(1, 0, 0, 1),
    closeBottom: false,
    height: 1000,
    extrudedHeight: 50100
}
});

var greenPolygon = viewer.entities.add({
name : 'Green polygon',
polygon : {
    hierarchy : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray([-118.0, 42.0,
                                                    -100.0, 42.0,
                                                    -104.0, 32.0]),
    // The alpha of 0.996 turns off the Z buffer.
    material : new Cesium.Color(0, 1, 0, 0.29),
    height: 50100,
    extrudedHeight: 95000,
    closeBottom: false
}
    });

viewer.zoomTo(viewer.entities);
```